Better way to model errors on Android
I was trying typed error handling on android using the Either<L,R> monad by Arrow. However, I encountered a problem trying to model the errors for different tasks.
Let's say there are two sets of specific errors for two tasks
sealed interface BookFlightError {
    data class PaymentFailed(val cause: String) : BookFlightError
}

sealed interface SignUpError {
    data object UsernameNotAvailable : SignUpError
    data object UserAlreadyExists : SignUpError
}

Now, apart from these task-specific errors, some errors like Authorization error will be common to most tasks and therefore need to be modelled somehow. Although redundant, one way is to repeat the common errors for each tasks such as
sealed interface BookFlightError {
    data class PaymentFailed(val cause: String) : BookFlightError
    data object AuthError : BookFlightError
}

sealed interface SignUpError {
    data object UsernameNotAvailable : SignUpError
    data object UserAlreadyExists : SignUpError
    data object AuthError : SignUpError
}

I would love some suggestions on how you accomplish this. Thank you!

I'd really HIGHLY suggest using exceptions instead.  Your code will not be understood or maintainable by anyone else using this paradigm.  Nobody does functional programming in Kotlin (few enough people do functional programming at all, doing it in Kotlin is even rarer).

Trusting people to properly check a return code (which is all this is) is a bad idea-  40 years of proof in C and other languages that return codes get ignored.
